# iPad EPub layout landscape/portrait issue

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, epub

I'm building a simple EPub with Indesign 5 to simply display a few images with a title above.

When I hold my iPad on portrait mode I have this (title above image which is what I want!):

[image: portrait orientation]

When I hold my iPad in Landscape mode I have the title alone and the image alone on the following page (I want title and image together though!):

[image: landscape orientation]

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that it may not be possible to do this unless you have CS5.5; [this article](http://blogs.adobe.com/vikrant/2011/04/epub-and-html-export-in-indesign-cs5-5/) states:

**Image Size**
In addition to “Fixed”, CS5.5 now supports a setting called “Relative to Page”. This sets a relative % width value based on the size of the image relative to the InDesign page width. The net effect is that images scale proportionally on different size computer screens or adjust to size of the browser window for desktop EPUB readers like Adobe Digital Editions.